# Show popover via Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, grails, popover

I am  trying to show popover on hover of an image,the content of  popover is a response of Ajax call to a template.With in this template I have tag (which used in taglib) in which my template of popover is rendered.In my response I am able to get my popover content but it is not displayed on hover of image.

Edit:
This is my tag which is used in template:

```
<cv:advice resumeSection="Additional" fieldId="int" resume="${resume}"/>
```

And The taglib in which tag is used:

```
def advice = { attrs, body ->
    Resume resume = attrs.resume
    String resumeSection = attrs.resumeSection
    String fieldId = attrs.fieldId
    AdviceBox adviceBox =   AdviceBox.findByResumeSectionAndFieldIdAndResumeType(resumeSection, fieldId,   ResumeType.findById(1))
    if (adviceBox) {
        out << g.render(template: "../templates/popover", model: [adviceBox: adviceBox, resumeSection: resumeSection, fieldId: fieldId])
    }
}
```

And Code of popover template is:

```
<a href="#" class="popover-with-html" rel="popover" data-html="true"    data-trigger="hover" title="${adviceBox?.title}" data-content="${adviceBox?.content}">
<img onclick="adviceEvent('${resumeSection}', '${fieldId}');" src="${g.resource(dir:  'images/CvSurgeonLegacy', file: 'question_mark.gif')}"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your data is coming in html format?

Comment: Ya,Sure........I have Checked It via alert()

Comment: please post your html code.

Comment: This is generated html:    <a class="popover-with-html" data-content="It is not always recommended to include a hobbies and interests section. If you feel it will be of benefit, because your interests are related to the position you are applying for, then include it." title="" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" rel="popover" href="#" data-original-title="Hobbies and Interests">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

```
$('.popover-with-html').popover();
```

after ajax response. It should work.

Ref : [popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers)